# White 100% box CSS issue with vertical scroll

Tags: css, removing-whitespace

So I am working on a webstie:

http://nexba.com.au/

Anyway, there is a strange floating box on the right hand side of the page that appears when there is vertical scrolling. This is not an issue on all of the other pages and I can't work out how o fix it.

If you could work out the CSS issue that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: may be you talk about horizontal scrolling

Comment: Which browser is giving you trouble? And on which page(s) specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! haha, that took some digging.

It's your facebook iframe! it's 450px wide! It doesn't need to be, and it is causing the horizontal scroll issue.

Answer (score 0):

May be is not a problem with vertical scrolling but It's horizontal scrolling. So; You have to define `min-width` in your `background_repeat` div. write this:

```
#background_repeat {
    min-width: 1300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you put your repeating background on the body tag instead of the #background-repeat element? That would solve the min-width issue. It looks like you have a background-image set on the body, but it's missing.